# Bootstrap row - removing an element causes the row to not fill properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a shopify theme that uses bootstrap..

I need to display a list of images which has been no problem, list displays properly.

However, I need to remove a specific list item and when doing this, I get wonky results... heres an example:

Assume "--" is the image, the third row appears when I choose not to display a specific image.

I've looked through the bootstrap documentation but I think im missing something.

```
     -- -- -- --
     -- -- -- --
              --
     -- -- -- --
     -- -- -- --
```

---

```
<div class="row seminar-row-two">
  {% for product in collections.stone-sculpture-gallery.products %}
  {% if product != 'john' %}
    {% assign productID = product.id %}
    {% assign productTitle = product.title %}
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-sm-6 gallery-image">
    {% for image in product.images %}
        {%if forloop.index == 1%}
        <a href="../products/{{product.handle}}"><img src="{{ image.src | product_img_url: 'medium' }}"> </a> 
        <p> <a href="../products/{{product.handle}}">{{product.handle}} </a> </p>
        {%endif%}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
  {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net with the produced HMTL? it's harder to debug otherwise.... Also, see our page about creating an [mcve] and adding them to your question.   It generates faster answers

Answer (score 1):

All col's are being entered into a single row which appears to be the issue. Having a new row every 4 elements should solve this.

Comment: You can probably use `clearfix` to solve this as well.